# I want to make an sql query has timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-update, locking

In my asp.net mvc application , I use Sql Data Adapter to update a record.

For example

```
 UPDATE sample SET status = 1 WHERE id = @id
```

I need to test a scenerio where this sql code cannot be run and not any records are updated. How can i make this?

Should i make a lock for sample table and how can i do that ? 
How can i make this UPDATE query somehow not works and not updates any record ?

Forgot to note that: I cannot change this code or application code and cannot give random @id parameter.

I need to do that in database level.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the specific table in database read only by using one of the below techniques.

- Insert, Update, Delete Trigger
- Check Constraint and Delete Trigger
- Make the Database Read Only
- Put the Table in a Read Only File Group
- DENY Object Level Permission
- Create a View

Comment: Write a script to `DENY` or `ALLOW` object level permission and either schedule it, or run it as required

Answer (score 0):

You could set id to a value that does not exist for sure (e.g. -1).

Or you could remove the user rights of the user accessing the database (in the connection string) for updating this table. Hoping it's not sa :)

Comment: I cannot change code and give a not-existing id. Application is running and  cannot modify parameter outside. The @id is always valid there.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [Authorize] attribute to the controller in question and attempt to perform the operation as a guest user.

Edit. To do it server side, enter the following to a query window on the database

```
Begin Transaction
```

That should lock up the database while you do your tests